# What is the number of self dual boolean functions?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, boolean-algebra

The dual of a Boolean function $F(x_1,x_2 \dots x_n,+,\bullet)$, written as $F^D$, is the same expression as that of $F$ with $+$ and $\bullet$ swapped. $F$ is said to be self-dual if $F=F^D$. What is the number of self-dual functions with $n$ Boolean variables?

I have no clue where to begin with. Any subtle hint would be great.

Thanks !

Comment: I have got this link : http://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/~masgax/sheet3-s.pdf, but I'm still stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. the notion of dual **function** you introduce is not well-defined. A self-dual **expression** is well-defined but a given function can have two expressions, one being self-dual and the other not self-dual, for example: $x$ and $x∙x$ both define the identity function but one expression is self-dual, the other not.
   (here, I suppose that you're working with the $Z/2Z$ ring, *i.e.* $+$ is XOR and $∙$ is AND, but the same problem arises in the Boolean lattice, *i.e.* OR/AND setting).
2. the classical definition of self-dual boolean function is a function that commutes with the permutation 0/1 (*i.e.* negation $\neg$), precisely: $f(x_1,...,x_n) = \neg f(\neg x_1, ..., \neg x_n)$.
3. the origin of your confusion maybe comes from the fact that the dual of a **monotonic** function (i.e. in the OR/AND setting) is obtained by inverting OR and AND *in the minimal disjunctive form*.

So what do you want to count: self-dual expressions (in which setting)? self-dual function in the classical sense? self-dual monotonic functions?

**Update after comment:**
For monotone self-dual function, two possible approaches:

1. any such function can be written as composition a ternary majority gate (Post's lattice theory): there's a proof in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5523/monotone-self-dual-boolean-functions-clone), maybe [this paper](http://www.lab2.kuis.kyoto-u.ac.jp/~kenya/COCOON2012.pdf) can help.
2. the irredundant disjunctive normal form might also help, or [this paper about decomposition and coteries](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0012365X9400053L)

Comment: I'm looking for the 3rd one.

Comment: Does this really answer? I'm unable to deduce any simplified inference. Can you please elaborate a little more without the need of going through the 'papers'?

Answer (score 1):

For any self-dual function, the number of it's minterms must be equal to it's number of maxterms. Also, no two complementary minterms must be present in the function. By complementary minterms, I mean those whose sum is equal to $n$, the number of variables of the function.
Hence there will be $2^{n-1}$ such complementary minterm pairs, one can select atmost one minterm from each of the pairs and should select one from all pairs to get a self dual function. That can be done in $2^{2^{n-1}}$ ways, which gives the total number of self dual functions.